# how to make the block continue from the new position

Tags: html, css

hello everyone i have an idea and I don't  know how to do it.

second div have p who length is auto, and i want to auto wrap div

[image]

Comment: for better understanding provide complete code to achieve your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting some width to 'first-div' and setting 'float: left'. So that rest of the space is allocated to the 'second-div'. Check the sample css here. Let's say the first div has class 'first-div':

```
.first-div {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

See the working example:

```css
div {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.first-div {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first-div border">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quis perferendis atque voluptatem iste non ex voluptatibus rem architecto laboriosam fugiat dolorum aspernatur nulla doloribus harum nostrum labore, id iure!
  </div>
  <div class="second-div">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quis perferendis atque voluptatem iste non ex voluptatibus rem architecto laboriosam fugiat dolorum aspernatur nulla doloribus harum nostrum labore, id iure! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quis perferendis atque voluptatem iste non ex voluptatibus rem architecto laboriosam fugiat dolorum aspernatur nulla doloribus harum nostrum labore, id iure!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quis perferendis atque voluptatem iste non ex voluptatibus rem architecto laboriosam fugiat dolorum aspernatur nulla doloribus harum nostrum labore, id iure!
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quis perferendis atque voluptatem iste non ex voluptatibus rem architecto laboriosam fugiat dolorum aspernatur nulla doloribus harum nostrum labore, id iure!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```